# How to set up / configure R for a dev, stage, and production environment on one server?

Tags: r, development-environment, production-environment

A colleague needs to set up a dev, stage and production environment on our server and he is asking what this means for how to run our R codes. Frankly, I do not know. My intuitive solution would be to have three different servers, so the installed R packages do not conflict. But for now, the environments should be on the same server. I am not sure how to achieve this. How can we run several versions of a package side by side? For example, using different .libPaths to be able to host different packages side by side?

**What is the proper way to set this up?**

PS. I hope I expressed myself clear enough, as I do not have any experience with this stuff.

Comment: Kind of a broad question, but maybe create a separate user account for each of dev, staging, and production, so that the default library paths a distinct from one another.

Answer (score 2):

Every GNU program allows you to prefix its installation (and more, as eg a suffix or prefix appended to the executable).

We use that in the ['how to build R-devel script'](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-debian/2012-August/001935.html) I posted years and and still use, directly and eg in the `Dockerfile` scripts for Rocker.

This generalizes easily. Use different configurations (with/without (memory) profiling, UBSAN, ...) and/or versions to you content, place them next to each other in `/opt/R` or `/usr/local/lib/R` or ... and *just use them as every R installation has its own separate file tree*.  One easy way to access them differently is via `$PATH`, another is to just have front-end scripts (or shell aliases) `R-prod`, `R-qa`, `R-dev`, etc pp

You will have to think through of you want a common `.libPaths()` (for, say, common dependencies) or whether you want to reinstall all libraries for each.  The latter is the default.